# How to create .NET-compatible events in F#?

Tags: .net, events, f#

I am trying to publish an event from an F# type, but I want it to be seen as an event from C# or VB. It seems that the correct way to do it used to be IEvent.create_HandlerEvent, but this function doesn't exist in the newest version of F#. So what is the correct way to do it now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Events are not my forte, but this example seems to work on F# 1.9.6.16:

```
namespace EventExample
open System
type MyEventArgs(msg:string) =
    inherit EventArgs()
    member this.Message = msg

type MyEventDelegate = delegate of obj * MyEventArgs -> unit

type Foo() = 
    let ev = new Event<MyEventDelegate, MyEventArgs>()

    member this.Ping(msg) =
        ev.Trigger(this, new MyEventArgs(msg))

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.GotPinged = ev.Publish
```

See also

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10555.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it works :) May I ask how did you know about the CLIEventAttribute? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the documentation/language specification/google...

Comment: I know because I'm a developer on the F# team, so I have 'inside information'.  :)  Yeah, this seems to be missing from the release notes and the spec; we'll be doing a spec update soon.
(Feel free to give me an upvote in addition to the check mark. :) )

Comment: What happened to the IEvent interface described in Expert F#?

Comment: We've iterated on the event design a couple times since the book was published... if there's an example you have trouble translating to the newer APIs, ask.

Comment: +1 this was more useful than MSDN!. Any plans for Don (or anyone else) to release an updated version of Expert f#? It previously was my bible for doing things but sadly I'm hitting unfortunate brick walls with parts that have changed in the ...9.16 release

Comment: Don et al. are working on an update to Expert F# currently, yes.