# F# IEvent.create

Tags: f#

Where is it gone ?

```
let triggerFindNext,findNextEvent = IEvent.create<EventArgs>()
```

The field, constructor or member 'create' is not defined

maybe I must to add some Framework for it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create .NET-compatible events in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904235/how-to-create-net-compatible-events-in-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IEvent.create` function has been deprecated. A new way of creating events is to create instance of the `Event` type. In the simplest case you can write just this:

```
let evt = new Event<EventArgs>() 

// Trigger event (instead of first element of the tuple)
evt.Trigger()
// Returns IEvent<EventArgs> value (instead of second element of the tuple)
evt.Publish
```

This represents event using `IEvent<_>` value (and doesn't generate .NET compatible event if you expose it as a property) and it uses generic `Handler<_>` delegate from F# libraries.

(If you want to generate .NET compatible event usable from C# then you need to add `CLIEvent` attribute and you can use variant of `Event` that takes delegate as generic parameter as described in [the answer already mentioned by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904235/how-to-create-net-compatible-events-in-f))

**EDIT**: I posted a more complete F# snippet (with nicer formatting) here: http://fssnip.net/1d